# How to find the best match between two pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have two dataframes, df1 and df2 as shown here:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp_A': [0.6, 1.1, 1.6, 2.1, 2.6, 3.1, 3.6, 4.1, 4.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 6.6, 7.1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp_B': [2.2, 2.7, 3.2, 3.7, 5.2, 5.7]})


Timestamp_A
0   0.6
1   1.1
2   1.6
3   2.1
4   2.6
5   3.1
6   3.6
7   4.1
8   4.6
9   5.1
10  5.6
11  6.1
12  6.6
13  7.1

Timestamp_B
0   2.2
1   2.7
2   3.2
3   3.7
4   5.2
5   5.7
```

Each dataframe is the output of different sensor readings, and each is being transmitted at the same frequency. What I would like to do, is to align these two dataframes together such that each timestamp in B aligns with the timestamp in A closest to it's value. For all values in Timestamp_A which do not have a match to Timestamp_B, replace them with np.nan. Does anyone have any advice for the best way to go about doing something like this? Here is the desired output:

```
    Timestamp_A     Timestamp_B
0   0.6     NaN
1   1.1     NaN
2   1.6     NaN
3   2.1     2.2
4   2.6     2.7
5   3.1     3.2
6   3.6     NaN
7   4.1     NaN
8   4.6     NaN
9   5.1     5.2
10  5.6     5.7
11  6.1     NaN
12  6.6     NaN
13  7.1     NaN
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want some application of [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp_A': [0.6, 1.1, 1.6, 2.1, 2.6, 3.1, 3.6, 4.1, 4.6, 5.1, 5.6, 6.1, 6.6, 7.1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Timestamp_B': [2.2, 2.7, 3.2, 3.7, 5.2, 5.7]})

df3 = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, left_on='Timestamp_A', right_on='Timestamp_B',
                    tolerance=0.5, direction='nearest')

print(df3)
```

Output as follows:

```
    Timestamp_A  Timestamp_B
0           0.6          NaN
1           1.1          NaN
2           1.6          NaN
3           2.1          2.2
4           2.6          2.7
5           3.1          3.2
6           3.6          3.7
7           4.1          3.7
8           4.6          NaN
9           5.1          5.2
10          5.6          5.7
11          6.1          5.7
12          6.6          NaN
13          7.1          NaN
```

The tolerance will define what "not having a match" means numerically, so that is up to you to determine.

Comment: interesting, the API says that tolerance only accepts integers or timedelta, so I did not even try to use it. good approach!

Comment: @Terry hah I didn't even see that, I just bull-headedly rushed in & tried it XD sometimes the docs lie I guess

Answer (score 2):

When you only have two `columns` and one value assignment , I feel like `reindex` is more suitable

```
df2.index=df2.Timestamp_B
df1['New']=df2.reindex(df1.Timestamp_A,method='nearest',tolerance=0.5).values
df1
Out[109]: 
    Timestamp_A  New
0           0.6  NaN
1           1.1  NaN
2           1.6  NaN
3           2.1  2.2
4           2.6  2.7
5           3.1  3.2
6           3.6  3.7
7           4.1  3.7
8           4.6  NaN
9           5.1  5.2
10          5.6  5.7
11          6.1  5.7
12          6.6  NaN
13          7.1  NaN
```

---

For more columns

```
s=pd.DataFrame(df2.reindex(df1.Timestamp_A,method='nearest',tolerance=0.5).values,index=df1.index,columns=df2.columns)
df1=pd.concat([df1,s],axis=1)
```

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to state that each dataframe I'm working with actually has hundreds of columns. If there were only 2 then this is absolutely a valid solution. It's certainly still a good thing to know